# Can I customize system-generated chatter posts?

Tags: community, chatter

I want to know if I can customize chatter post/text that are automatically generated by the system, for example:

```
00001006 — Mike Caseem created a case.
```

Comment: Hi aelias, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

You can't customize what is generated by the system, but you can have it create your own custom post with a trigger.

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element.htm):

```
ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), '0F9d0000000TreH', ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem, 'On vacation this week.');
```

You can also look into an [AppExchange app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B52CxEAJ) that would allow you to do this.

Comment: @aelias is talking about posts, not emails...

Answer (score 1):

To add onto what brezotom said, no, you can't customize the system generate posts.

What you can do is use a trigger and some code to add another post/record to the FeedItem with the ParentId being that case. You can query Case posts via the `CaseFeed` by the `Type` if you want as well to find what's system generated vs user generated.

See here: [Chatter Analysis](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145219/query-chatter-feed-topics-and-groups) to see the work I've gone through to map out how the `FeedItem`, `CaseFeed`, and `FeedComment` intertwine.

Best of luck!